# How to make a text object/motion with begining and ending pattern in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to define a text object like `iw`, `aB` and the other ones listed in `:help text-objects` that defines an area beginning with some pattern and ending with another.  More precisely, I would like to define a text object which starts with some `{pattern1}` and ends with some `{pattern2}`.  The patterns included.  It is important that it can stretch over multiple lines (like `aB` but unlike `a"`).

The examples I have in mind are for selecting in-line equations in LaTeX, that is, everything between one `$` and the next `$` (including the `$`'s), and for selecting LaTeX environments like between `\begin{*}` and the following `\end{*}`, where the `*` here is just any string of characters (but non-greedy like `\{-}` in Vim regex).

I have tried to tried to look at [this guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects) at the Vim Tips Wiki, but I do not know how to replace `[z` and `]z` with something that searches backwards for some pattern and forwards for some patters, respectively, so that it works as I want it to.

So to give the example of the inline equation (lets say the text obejct is called `ad`), then, if the cursor was placed somewhere between the `$`'s in the following line:

```
it follows that $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} $ is two
```

in normal mode, and `vad` was pressed, then `$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} $` should be in visual, or if `dad` was pressed it should be deleted.

Comment: You mean something like [vim-textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex)? Create your own text objects with [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user). List of [more text objects](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki)

Comment: @PeterRincker: Yes it does some of what I want, though it does not really match as I had hoped with `\begin{*} ... \end{*}`.  In the plugin you mention, they don't have to match, so it would match all of `\begin{equation} A = \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{matrix}` if you used the environment-textobject with the cursor on the `A`.

Comment: Well that is not good. I have a feeling that making this work would require a non-trivial amount of work and outside the scope of a SO post. It might be worth creating a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex/issues).

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned Vim Tips Wiki page lists the two plugins (under "Related scripts") that make defining new text objects very easy:

- [textobj-user](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) is very flexible and generic
- [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) (by me) is specially written for text objects defined by start and end patterns

The following call defines an `ad` text object for text inside `$...$`:

```
call CountJump#TextObject#MakeWithCountSearch('', 'd', 'a', 'v', '\$', '\$')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes I can see how the CountJump plugin can be used to add text objects for `$...$`, but can it also do something like `\begin{-} ... \end{-}`.  The problem is that it should not match `\begin{center} \end{equation}`, say.  I have tried to look at textobj-user, but I find it quite difficult to understand how it works.

Comment: CountJump doesn't yet support backreferences, but I take that as an enhancement request.